# What is this purple claw thing (Demon Altar) and what can I do with it?

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this monster (screenshot included)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/what-is-this-monster-screenshot-included)

I've found some sort of weird claw thing underground that looks like this

[image: Screenshot of the claw]

When I hit it with a hammer it does 48 damage to me, nothing else seems to have any effect.

What is it and does it have any use?

Comment: @Raven Since the answers on the old question are outdated, maybe you should consider merging or reversing the direction of the duplicate close